# Siphon and a pressure gradient

Tags: fluid-statics

It's claimed [here](https://www.lhup.edu/~dsimanek/museum/themes/siphon.htm) that the pressure gradient is what sustains the flow in a siphon. But I'm not really accustomed to the term and don't see why it forms and why it sustains the flow.

Can you please explain it?

Comment: Have you read the linked article in which [the chain model is refuted](http://www.phys.uhh.hawaii.edu/documents/TPT-final.pdf)?